# Executing main class while thread sleeps - java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Can someone help me understand how threads function in java.

I have a main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new TestThread();
    new Thread(r).start();
    executor.execute(r);
    System.out.println("Hey the thread has ended")
}
```

and a thread class:

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable {
    public class TestThread() {
        sleep(20000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

How can I get the phrase:"Hey the thread has ended" without having to wait while the thread sleeps?

Comment: Remove the sleep from the constructor.

Comment: He asked to get the phrase without having to wait the sleep to finish so I presume that he can't remove the sleep, but he can stop the thread from working. :)

Comment: Where did that executor come from?

Comment: There is no thread sleeping except the main thread calling the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:
call the start method of the thread class, and in the Run implementation make the thread sleep...

**notice that your app is going to terminate before the Thread returns from the sleep and continues**

## The Runnable class

```
    public class TestThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setParameter(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

## The implementation

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestThread r = new TestThread();
    r.setParameter("myParameterHere");
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setName("asdas");
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Hey the thread has ended");
}
```

Comment: "come back to continue" - you might want to reword this phrase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. how can I implement this if I wanna pass an argument into the run method?

Comment: add a method to your class and call it

Comment: You mean a setter? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in what is arguably it's most simple form.

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }

    }

}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable r = new TestThread();
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    // No it hasn't!
    //System.out.println("Hey the thread has ended");
    t.join();
    // It has now!
    System.out.println("Hey the thread has ended");
}
```